# Create Outlook e-mail with formatting as shown on Excel sheet, using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a plain text e-mail in this format.
[image: Example of what I have]

I am trying to modify it to html to keep the formatting, or to be able to modify myself to have that formatting.

Cell b4 & b6 have formulas that automatically update some fields such as numbers & dates from another tab.

```vb
Sub sumit()
Dim mainWB As Workbook
Dim SendID
Dim CCID
Dim Subject
Dim Body
Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
SendID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B1").Value
CCID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B2").Value
Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B3").Value
Body = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B4").Value & vbNewLine & mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B6").Value & vbNewLine & mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B8").Value & vbNewLine & mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B11").Value

With olMail
    .To = SendID
    If CCID <> "" Then
        .CC = CCID
    End If
    .Subject = Subject
    .Body = Body
    .Display
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .Body, use .htmlBody

ie,

```
strHTML = "<html><body>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<h2>Thank you very much for your order. Attached is a copy of your order acknowledgement.</h2>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</body></html>"
.htmlBody = strHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use function to convert range to html. it will create temporary workbook.
below function what u need to paste on standard module.

```
Public Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

and yours code edited. iam not sure that i correctly set rng_Body so check it.

```
Sub sumit()
Dim mainWB As Workbook
Dim SendID
Dim CCID
Dim Subject
Dim rng_Body as range
Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
set rng_Body = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").usedrange

SendID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B1").Value
CCID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B2").Value
Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("B3").Value


With olMail
.To = SendID
If CCID <> "" Then
.CC = CCID
End If
.Subject = Subject
.htmlbody = "some text upper" & vbcrlf &  RangetoHTML(rng_Body) & vbcrlf & "Some text below"
.Display
```